# Need help partitioning Linux Mint SSD

Tags: linux-mint, partition, gparted

I would need advice on how to partition my ssd correctly to add non-allocated free space to `sdb4` (please see the picture).

My PC has 3 data drives, `nvme0n1` carries *Windows*, `sda` data, and `sdb` is *Linux Mint 19.2* installed. I installed Linux Mint after Windows and somehow I partitioned the drive wrongly. What I would like to do now is shifting the free space to `sdb4`, but `gparted` doesn't offer that option even when I try it from a Gparted Live USB version.

I would be very thankful for any hints on how to partition correctly without the need to re-install my already configured Linux Mint installation. Could I maybe safely delete `sdb3`? Many thanks in advance!

Further `sdb3` holds the flag `"bios_grub"` and the warning:

```
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sdb3 is missing
```

[image]

Comment: `/dev/sdb3` is a bootloader partition to boot GRUB from a GPT partitioned drive in BIOS (non-UEFI) mode. You need it if you don't boot from UEFI. Can you select `/dev/sdb3` and move it to the left next to `/dev/sdb1` so that your unallocated space on the left side is zero? If this works you can resize `sdb4` afterwards.

Comment: If Windows on NVMe drive is UEFI, you may want an ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32 with boot flag. And drive should be gpt for UEFI boot. Your swap is huge. New versions of Ubuntu now use swap file. You might only need larger swap if hibernating & hibernating not normally recommended. Many of us also like to separate / (root) from data, either separate /home and/or /data partitions.

Comment: Thank you both @Freddy and `oldfred`, this helped a lot and I could finally solve it! Sorry it took so long. If `freddy` could you post your answer below, I will mark it as correct.